# FB messenger checkbox messaging_optins send message to user_ref_id not working "You cannot send messages to this id"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I tried to send a message to my customer after they put an order if they check the FB Messenger checkbox plugin on the checkout page.

I already follow step-by-step the FB docs of this plugin
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin/

All are fine and works until I want to try to send the message to the `user_ref_id` that I defined before and it just thrown error to me.

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "(#100) Parameter error: You cannot send messages to this id",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Aev08w-rkwIfurCKj79g2R0"
}
```

I was succeed and able to receive the webhook `messaging_optins` as like below

```
{
"value": {
    "object": "page",
    "entry": [{
        "id": "xxxxx",
        "time": 1617868589319,
        "messaging": [{
            "recipient": {
                "id": "xxxxx"
            },
            "timestamp": 1617868589319,
            "optin": {
                "ref": "test=haha",
                "user_ref": "2020092411511430212"
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

I already check my `app_id` and `page_id` both are correct, and I also use the `access_token` that I generate from FB developer Messenger section is correct too.

Here's my code to send the message

```
$messageData = [
        "recipient" => [
            "id" => '202009241151143024'
        ],
        "message" => [
            "text" => 'hello'
        ]
    ];
    $ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=xxx');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: application/json"]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($messageData));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_exec($ch);
```

I don't know where's the mistakes or maybe I skipped some step when setting it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us how you are actually trying to send the message.

Comment: @CBroe I just update the post with the code when I tried to send the message. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I already found my mistakes

i use `id` instead of `user_ref` when I tried to send a message to my customer.

Here's the correction code when send the message.

```
$messageData = [
    "recipient" => [
        "user_ref" => '202009241151143024'
    ],
    "message" => [
        "text" => 'hello'
    ]
];
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=xxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: application/json"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($messageData));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_exec($ch);
```